# $S=[\frac{1}{x_1 +1} +\frac{1}{x_2 +1}+........+\frac{1}{x_m +1}]$

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sequence is defined by $x_{k-1}=x_k^2 + x_k$ and$x_1 =1/2$ . we have to find the value of $S=[\frac{1}{x_1 +1} +\frac{1}{x_2 +1}+........+\frac{1}{x_m +1}]$ where m is a natural number where [.]denotes greatest integer function.

by substituting few values such as m=1,2 I got answer as 1 .

But could not understand what is the proper method .

Comment: How was your advance?

Comment: @ArchisWelankar good

Comment: How much do you expect?. (Are you studying maths in pleasure time?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**  $\frac{1}{x_k+1}=\frac{1}{x_k}-\frac{1}{x_{k+1}}$.